# Need to correct VBA code. Getting error message."For Control Variable already in use"

Tags: excel, vba

Im using VBA in Excel.

Im getting an error message saying control variable already in use. When the error pops up the second **For Each r In** is highlighted in the VBA editor.Can anyone help correcting this code. Thank you

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk", 1) > 0 Then
        For Each r In ws.Range("C118:I124")
        For Each r In ws.Range("C163:J168")
        For Each r In ws.Cell(E2, E15, E28, E41, E54, E67, E80)
            r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
        Next r
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: every `For Each` loop must be closed with a corresponding `Next` statement. your code has "opened" 4 `For Each` loops but "closed" only two of them. Moreover the two innermost `For Each` loops share the same looping variable (`r`) as the outer one, and that's not possible: every loop must have its own looping variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run through three separate ranges, i.e. concatenating these ranges. That is not how the `For-Each` works, however, and you'll have to break it up.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk", 1) > 0 Then
        For Each r In ws.Range("C118:I124")
            r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
        Next r

        For Each r In ws.Range("C163:J168")
            r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
        Next r

        Range("E2").Formula = Replace(Range("E2").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E2").Parent.Name)
        Range("E15").Formula = Replace(Range("E15").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E15").Parent.Name)
        Range("E28").Formula = Replace(Range("E28").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E28").Parent.Name)
        Range("E41").Formula = Replace(Range("E41").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E41").Parent.Name)
        Range("E54").Formula = Replace(Range("E54").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E54").Parent.Name)
        Range("E67").Formula = Replace(Range("E67").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E67").Parent.Name)
        Range("E80").Formula = Replace(Range("E80").Formula, "Wk1", Range("E80").Parent.Name)
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

EDIT: Changed to accommodate comment. It ain't gettin'any prettier, but I'm afraid there's no method to make calling several loose cells any more elegant.

Comment: Thanks,. ive tried that code but now im getting an error message with cell E2 in the code highlighted saying variable not defined

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type up the code. I pasted it into the editor but im getting an "Object variable or with block variable not set" error message. There is also a quote missing around E54 in the code you typed in case someone wants to use it.

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied my bad: in the last part, change the `r.formula` to `Range("EXX").Formula` i.,e. the same code as on the left side of the `=`.

Comment: dont undertand . when you say the last part , do you mean the last time r.formula appears in the code. What is ("EXX"). can you type it

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied Answer is edited. But - without wanting to sound harsh - why are you writing VBA when you don't grasp these instructions or debug this kind of errors?

Comment: im new to vba. Im trying to pick it up

Comment: code works perfectly. Thank you again for taking the time to help.